# how to force order in DEPENDS while preparing recipe-sysroot?

Tags: yocto

i have added dependencies through DEPENDS +=. While do_prepare_recipe_sysroot, what order does it follow while copying to recipe-sysroot?
How I can enforce this order?

eg:
for recipeA

DEPENDS += "recipeB recipeC"

DEPENDS += "recipeD"

where as recipeB depends on recipeD.

Here recipeC and recipeD both populate header.h. which one will be include in the recipe-sysroot.

Comment: This often indicates a bad design if you have two recipes which provide the same header but only one is necessary.
Maybe recipeC and recipeD should both depend on a library build with recipeE that contains header.h

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Dependencies ordering is automatically done by Yocto. Same file cannot be provided by different recipes. You will get error like below,

```
Exception: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists:
```

So you need to fix up the path. For example, if recipe C is for Application X, then you should try `usr/include/X/header.h` and `usr/include/Y/header.h` for recipe D or you should name is differently.

As far as dependency is concerned, you don't need to worry about the ordering. Yocto automatically parses and identifies which one to compile first in it's task queue.